# ng-repeat within angular ui tooltip

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

I am using angular bootstrap tooltip but i am struggling to get an ng-repeat to work within the tooltip itself.

Here is the code I am trying to use below. please can anyone help

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="usertooltip.html">
    <div ng-repeat='u in g.Users'>{{u.UserName}}</div>
</script>

<div class="users col-lg-2">
    <a href="#" tooltip-template="usertooltip.html" tooltip-trigger tooltip-animation="false" tooltip-placement="top">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-user tb-blue" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{ g.Users.length }} / {{ g.MaximumUsers }}
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: could you make a plunker and post the link here? would be easier to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the $parent scope in your tooltip.

```
<div ng-repeat='u in $parent.g.Users'>{{u.UserName}}</div>
```

Comment: g is the top as above g is another ng-repeat (g in vm.gameList)